# How to get the ControlType?

Tags: c#, winforms

I created a new class that create a control and position the control automatically above another control:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Adding_Controls
{
    public enum ControlType
    {
        Label,
        Button,
        TextBox
    }

    public class AddControlsAbove
    {
        public static void AddControlAbove(Control target, ControlType controlType, string[] texts, Font font, int verticalGapAboveTarget = 0, int horizontalGapBetweenControls = 0, Color[] backgroundColors = null, Color[] foregroundColors = null)
        {
            int startingY = target.Location.Y - verticalGapAboveTarget;
            List<Control> controls = new List<Control>();

            int numControls = texts.Length;
            int numColors = Math.Max(backgroundColors?.Length ?? 0, foregroundColors?.Length ?? 0);

            // Create controls
            for (int i = 0; i < numControls; i++)
            {
                Control newControl;
                switch (controlType)
                {
                    case ControlType.Label:
                        newControl = new Label() { Text = texts[i], Font = font };
                        break;
                    case ControlType.Button:
                        newControl = new Button() { Text = texts[i], Font = font };
                        break;
                    default:
                        throw new ArgumentException("Invalid ControlType specified.");
                }

                // Set background and foreground color if specified
                if (numColors > 0)
                {
                    newControl.BackColor = backgroundColors[i % numColors];
                    newControl.ForeColor = foregroundColors[i % numColors];
                }

                newControl.Size = new Size(newControl.PreferredSize.Width, newControl.PreferredSize.Height);
                controls.Add(newControl);
                target.Parent.Controls.Add(newControl);
            }

            // Position controls
            int totalWidth = 0;
            foreach (var control in controls)
            {
                totalWidth += control.Width;
            }
            totalWidth += horizontalGapBetweenControls * (controls.Count - 1);

            int startingX = target.Location.X + (target.Width / 2) - (totalWidth / 2);

            int x = startingX;
            foreach (var control in controls)
            {
                control.Location = new Point(x, startingY - control.Height);
                x += control.Width + horizontalGapBetweenControls;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

then using it in form1:

```
private string[] controlsAbove;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Font labelFont = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 12);
    Color[] backgroundColors = { Color.Red, Color.Green };
    Color[] foregroundColors = { Color.White, Color.Black };

    controlsAbove = new string[] { "Label1" };

    AddControlsAbove.AddControlAbove(progressBarEx1, ControlType.Label, controlsAbove, labelFont, 10, 50, backgroundColors, foregroundColors);
}
```

now I have one label control above the progressBarEx1

but now I want to do something else , I have in the form1 designer already  a Label control name lblProgress and I want to get the ControlType from the AddControlAbove method and to be able to assign it to the lblProgress.

something like:

```
lblProgress = AddControlsAbove.AddControlAbove(progressBarEx1, ControlType.Label, controlsAbove, labelFont, 10, 50, backgroundColors, foregroundColors);
```

and that the method AddControlAbove will return the control type in this case the ControlType.Label

because i'm using lblProgress already in my form1 code in some places I want to use this lblProgress as the control that will be positioned automatically above the progressBarEx1.

Comment: If I understand correctly, it shouldn't be "progressBarEx1" in your line "lblProgress = ..." but "lblProgress" instead. Then, for you to get the ControlType in return, you have to replace "void" in the method inside your class "AddControlAbove" by "ControlType" and of course program the desired returning object in this very method. And for your latest sentence, I wonder how a same single control could be created in the designer and then by your method, this is something I don't get.

Comment: What I don't understand is why your method should return a ControlType because you give the ControlType you want in the arguments of the method.

Comment: @Fredy the progressBarEx1 is right because this is the target control.  i mean this is the target control where the created labels or other controls in the method AddControlAbove will positioned above.  so the target control is progressBarEx1

Comment: Ok thanks for the reply. Then I don't understand your need of return type: you can't write lblProgress = AddControlsAbove(etc.) because lblProgress is a label Control and the method AddControlAbove would return your enum ControlType, which is incoherent per se and moreover it is not the way to initialize a control. I hope you don't mind clarifying your aim because I still can't see it.